# How to change defaults.last_index_time format in solr

Tags: solr, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am using Apache Solr 6.2, and need a timestamp for defaults.last_index_time field or need separate field for a Core config.

Default value was  *defaults.last_index_time=2016-09-19 14:55:17* .

I need something like

```
defaults.last_index_time=1474297085558
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Property Writer to change **last_index_time** format in solr.Add the element to the DIH configuration file, directly under the dataConfig element

```
<propertyWriter dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX" type="SimplePropertiesWriter"  />
```

In Property Writer you can specify your desired format. But as it seems you want date in milliseconds. As there is no dateFormat available for that.

Comment: I tried this one to change format but there is no change in output