# Solr last_index_time difference timezone format so output is wrong

Tags: solr

Few days back I have started working on solr, and today I am facing a problem with deltaQuery.
my server timezone is IST also mysql is giving default output in IST.
but solr dataimport.properties file storing the timezone in UTC.

Problem is when I selecting the query `B.modified_on >'${dataimporter.last_index_time}'` then wrong time comparing because of timezone.
the solr logs are:- B.modified_on>'2016-09-23 07:39:10' and the server time is.
$ date
Fri Sep 23 15:22:20 IST 2016

Please suggest how to change solr timezone in IST or any other answer. I cann't my linux server timezone.

Comment: Someone already asked this.Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576281/how-to-change-defaults-last-index-time-format-in-solr/39581729#39581729

Comment: I don't why solr picking the different format as the logs also writing in different timezone.

Comment: The reason is because a server's clock always should be in UTC, and the timestamps are then converted based on the logging facility setting to the local TZ. It's not picking a different format - it's explicitly not picking anything, and just keeping it as UTC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solr logs by default are in UTC. To change this to IST, edit the solr.in.sh file to include the line:

```
# By default the start script uses UTC; override the timezone if needed

SOLR_TIMEZONE="IST"
```

Comment: Ohoo yes I have change the bin/solr file the SOLR_TIMEZONE=`date '+%Z'`.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CONVERT_TZ` function in MySQL to [convert a datetime field to UTC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz).

```
CONVERT_TZ(B.modified_on, 'IST', 'UTC') > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'
```

.. should work. Try it in a MySQL command line session to see that you're getting the correct UTC time back.